# Convert Gulp 3 functions to Gulp V4

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am following a tutorial on react that requires gilp. The gulpfile.js used in the tutorial is based on an older version of Gulp. I am trying to convert it to V4 but am not having much luck.

I want to ensure the code is correct and am finding that the changes that I add in make parts work, but I'm sure there is a better way to convert it. This is the original code provided in the tutorial:

```js
'use strict';

//dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');



///////////////
// - SCSS/CSS
///////////////

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

// Compile SCSS
gulp.task('compile_scss', function(){
    gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));



});

// Detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', function(){
    gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, [compile_scss]);
});




// Run tasks
gulp.task('default', ['watch_scss']);
```

All I am looking for is the correct way to convert the above into a gulp v4 version

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. However, I am not sure it is the most optimized code:

```
'use strict';

//dependencies
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const changed = require('gulp-changed');



///////////////
// - SCSS/CSS
///////////////

// Compile SCSS
function scss() {
    return gulp.src('./src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed('./src/Assets/css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/Assets/css'))
}

// Watch files
function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch('./src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss', scss);
}

exports.default = watchFiles;
```